# Variables from another file using JSON

Tags: json

In a json file, is it possible to have something similar to the below example where SOURCE_ADDRESSES and DESTINATION_ADDRESSES are variables that refer to a subset of data stored in another file?

```
<policy.json file>

#include '../../subnets/NETWORKS.inc'

{
    "source-address": SOURCE_ADDRESSES
    "destination-address": DESTINATION_ADDRESSES
    "protocol: "tcp"
    "action: "accept"
    "counter: "allow.iternetwork.traffic"
}


<NETWORKS.net file>

SOURCE_ADDRESSES
10.90.50.1
10.90.30.1
10.90.20.1

DESTINATION_ADDRESSES
10.80.50.1
10.80.30.1
10.80.20.1
```

Comment: I'm curious to know as well...